# Upper and lower case

Tags: c, uppercase, lowercase

I need to make program where I can insert a line with words, and program will make all words like first one(upper lower cases).

Example:
Insert line - AbbA hall fameee class

and the output of the program should be: - AbbA HalL FamEee ClaSs

How can I check full word, and get out what symbols there is - upper or lower? And then make all words with same scheme.

Comment: this is no "do my homework for me" website. Please show us your effort and where you are stuck, and we are eager to help

Comment: Yenots1, I am sure English is not your first language, but can you try one more time on that wording? Additionally, this question is not on-topic as it is, because you did not say what you have tried, just a problem for people to solve.

Comment: It appears that you want the leading character of a word capitalized, and then every 4th character uppercase as well.  To get significant help you need to specific exactly what you want.

Comment: I guess Yenots1 wants to apply the Upper/Lower case format of each character of the first word to the remaining words in the same order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Comment]
Create a boolean array and capture the upper/lower case information of each character of the first word. Using the same boolean array, format your remaining words. This is all I can help you for now. You can try writing a program and get back to the forum so that you can get more response. Since I do not have privilege to post comment am  adding my comment in answer section

[Answer]
Here you go...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char inputStr[] = "AbbA hall fameee class";
    char bool_arr[50];
    char *ptr;
    int len = 0;
    int loopcnt = 0;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Input Str: %s\n", inputStr);    

    ptr = strtok(inputStr, " ");
    len = strlen(ptr);

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(toupper(ptr[i]) != ptr[i]) {
            bool_arr[i] = 0;    //Lower case
        }
        else {
            bool_arr[i] = 1;    //Upper case
        }
    }

    while(ptr != NULL) {
        if(strlen(ptr) < len) {
            loopcnt = strlen(ptr);
        }
        else {
            loopcnt = len;
        }

        for(i = 0; i < loopcnt; i++) {
            if(bool_arr[i] == 0 && 
                (tolower(ptr[i]) != ptr[i])) {
                ptr[i] = tolower(ptr[i]);
            }

            if(bool_arr[i] == 1 && 
                (toupper(ptr[i]) != ptr[i])) {
                ptr[i] = toupper(ptr[i]);
            }
        }

        printf("%s ", ptr);     

        ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");    
    }
}
```

Comment: @Yenots1: yeah, now you only have to copy it and paste it into your homework! You acquired a useful skill today!

Answer (score 0):

```
char str[]=" AbbA hall fameee class";
int flag=0;
int i;

for(i=0;i<len(str);i++)
{
    if(flag==0 && str[i]==' ')
    {
        str[i+1]+=32;
        flag=1;
    }
    else
    {
        flag=0;
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you added some explanation. This is especially important with "homework help" type questions.

Comment: can't compile because of length.